# The minimum size of an edge set that contains an edge of every cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

The question is like this:

> There is a connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges such that $m \ge n$.
> Let's say that the graph has a spanning tree, meaning there is a tree $T$ such that $T = (V, E_t)$ and $E_t$ contained in $E$.
> Find the minimum size $k$ such that a set $F$ exists such that $F \subseteq E$ and these two conditions hold:
>
> - $|F| = k$
> - Every cycle in $G$ contains an edge in $F$.

My solution is like:

I know that $G$ has a spanning tree $T$.
A tree has $n-1$ edges so for going from $G$ to $T$ i need to erase a set of edges (call it $F$) that their size is $m - (n - 1)$ so after i erase them i have a subgraph of $G$ that has $n-1$ edges as needed for it to be a tree.

Let's say that there is a cycle in $G$ that doesn't contain an edge in $F$ so after I erase $F$ from $G$ this cycle will remain as it was and that is a contradiction to the assumption that $T$ is a tree. So, as a result of the contradiction it means that $F$ has to be a set of edges that $|F| = k$ and also every cycle in $G$ contain a set in $F$, now we need to prove that $k$ is the minimum size of a set like this. (Comment: $k = m - (n-1)$)

Let's say $m - (n-1)$ is not the minimum size, so we have $k < m - (n - 1)$ such that $k$ is the size of a set $F$ that every cycle in  $G$ contains a set in $F$. If we erase $F$ from $G$ we will get a subgraph $G_t$ which has $m - k$ edges so we can say that the number of edges in $G_t$ is bigger than $n-1$ and we know that the number of vertices is $n$.

Because $G$ is a connected graph and every edge that we erase is contained in a cycle in $G$, we can infer that $G_t$ is a connected graph. Because $G_t$ has more than $n-1$ edges and only $n$ vertices we can infer that $G_t$ is a connected graph that is not a tree and therefore $G_t$ has at least one cycle.
If $G_t$ has a cycle, its obvious that there is a cycle in $G$ that does not contain an edge in $F$. Therefore every group of edges that has more than $m - (n-1)$ edges does not satisfy the conditions.

The question is about the last step, if I am erasing an edge of a cycle, couldn't it stay a cycle without the edge? (Maybe if its stays a cycle it means that there is a subcycle in $G$ that doesn't contain an edge in $F$ and a subcycle is a cycle and there is the answer).

Just want to make sure, and I already wrote all of this so I will post it maybe it will help other people who faced this question.

Comment: Do you mean "group" in an informal sense (in which case *set* of arcs would be more clear) or is there really group theory going on here?

Comment: I mean set of arcs

Comment: By circle do you mean cycle? And intersection you mean vertex

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean

Comment: I've edited your question to correct the terminology. One comment: I changed "subgraph which is a tree" to "spanning tree" to indicate that it is a subgraph which keeps all the vertices of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is solid. To summarize: a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ has $n-1$ edges, and this is the most edges that a graph without cycles can have.

- We can delete the $m-n+1$ edges of $G$ which are not in $T$, and that is a valid solution (there are no surviving cycles, so we must have deleted at least one edge from every cycle).
- If $F$ is a set of fewer than $m-n+1$ edges, then $G-F$ has at least $n$ edges left, so it has at least one cycle: a cycle disjoint from $F$. So no such set can be a valid solution.

Now, on to your concern: if we are erasing an edge of a cycle, could it stay a cycle without that edge?

Well, not the cycle of **those exact vertices** in **that exact order**. If you have a cycle with vertices $a,b,c,d,e$ and edges $ab,bc,cd,de,ea$, and you delete one of those edges, that's not a cycle anymore. You might, in general, have some related cycles:

- A cycle like $a,c,e,b,d$ with edges $ac, ce, eb, bd, da$ which has those vertices in a different order, so it uses different edges.
- A cycle like $a,b,c,e$ with edges $ab, bc, ce, ea$ which has most of the same vertices in the same order, but skips some, so some edges are different. (If you delete edge $cd$ or $de$ from the first cycle, this cycle survives.)

We don't have to care about that in this proof, because we make sure to delete an edge from **every** cycle. When we consider cycle $a,b,c,d,e$, we conclude that we've deleted an edge from that cycle. When we consider cycle $a,b,c,e$, we conclude that we've deleted an edge from that cycle, too. It might be the same edge, or a different one; we don't particularly care.